# three.js Is there a way to determine if a given mesh face is visible?

Tags: three.js

I have selected a subset of faces (triangle) from one or more objects from the current scene. The camera is rotating around the scene.
I need to know which, if any, of the subset faces are visible at any time.

Is there an algorithm for doing this in three.js? The only way I can think of doing it is to project a ray from each face towards the camera. If it hits the camera without intersecting any other object then it must be visible to the camera. It would have to be done for each movement of the camera. Would that be an efficient method?

EDIT: This is a slight variation on [Check a face is upwards/downwards towards mouse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534006/check-a-face-is-upwards-downwards-towards-mouse-direction)
As I need to also know whether the face is visible to the camera not just "facing" it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check a face is upwards/downwards towards mouse direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534006/check-a-face-is-upwards-downwards-towards-mouse-direction)

Comment: @gaitat close, and interesting, but I need to also know whether the face is visible to the camera not just "facing" it.

Comment: then you have to look into the term `occlusion culling`